# Postgres only select rows with latin characters

Tags: postgresql

I want to use a condition in a `where` clause that specifies to only select rows with latin characters (and numbers). Currently I am trying this, but this also returns me rows with Cyrillic characters:

```
SELECT * FROM temp WHERE temp.name SIMILAR TO '%[^[:ascii:]]%';
```

How to only select rows that only contain latin characters (and numbers)?

Comment: Do you want to allow spaces, punctuation, etc too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regular expression:

```
... WHERE name ~ '^[[:ascii:]]*$' COLLATE "C"
```

That means that the pattern must consist entirely of ASCII characters. Note that control characters like “newline”, spaces and other ASCII symbols like `$` also are ASCII characters. If you want only letters and numbers, try

```
... WHERE name ~ '^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$' COLLATE "C"
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the `COLLATE "C"` standing for?

Comment: It specifies the binary collation. I doubt that it matters here.